# Android - How to make child LinearLayout match parent RelativeLayout's height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am putting this LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#66000000"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:src="@drawable/big_tick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I am trying to do is - to show which item has been chosen. I set LinearLayout's height and width match_parent. It is only matching parent(RelativeLayout)'s width, not height.

This is what I have intended to do:
[image]

This is what I am getting:
[image]

LinearLayout is not taking whole height of its parent.

There are 2 reasons, why I am using Relative layout as parent:

1. The LinearLayout should be in upside(should cover) book information with 40% black color
2. To show this symbol on the top of book

[image]

The whole XML looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="11dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCover"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="146dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#232425"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAuthor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#848586"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/llBook"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_round_book_status"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_new" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:src="@drawable/big_tick" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using this RelativeLayout in BaseAdapter class using which I am filling GridView with items.

```
public class LibraryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
RealmResults<RBook> rBooks;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public LibraryAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<RBook> rBooks) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rBooks = rBooks;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rBooks.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rBooks.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RBook rBook = (RBook) getItem(position);

    View view = convertView;

    if(view == null) {
        // new row is needed to inflate new row
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_library_book, parent, false);
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rBook.getCover() , 0, rBook.getCover().length);
    ImageView ivCover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivCover);
    ivCover.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText(rBook.getTitle());

    TextView tvAuthor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAuthor);
    tvAuthor.setText(rBook.getAuthor());

    return view;
}
```

}

---

**EDIT**:

**Try1**: as **cj1098** suggested I have changed child LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. Unfortunately, no effect

**Try2**: as **challenger** suggested, I have used this inside my child LinearLayout, but effect was like this:

[image]

**Try3**: as codeMagic suggested, I have changed child LinearLayout's

```
gravity="center"
```

to ImageView's

```
layout_gravity="center"
```

In result, LinearLayout is not taking whole height.

So my question is **how make child LinearLayout match parent RelativeLayout's height**?

Comment: in your RelativeLayout, the only drawable that I see, is the `@drawable/icon_new` the other book info is empty, no image, no texts. I don't know how you got the screenshot, please share your code where you set values. Maybe you set incorrect LayoutParams in your grid or list view. The `match_parent` of LinearLayout works in this case, since there is only a 'new badge' which is small and it wraps the 'V' image inside.

Comment: @sromku, I have added code for my BaseAdapter

Comment: @codeMagic gravity="center" specify that ImageView will be centered, we can also set this in ImageView, but use layout_gravity

Comment: @codeMagic, I have removed gravity="center" for my child LinearLayout. Instead, I have put layout_gravity="center". LinearLayout is not taking whole height(

Comment: Don't know why you have such effect. Maybe create linearlayout programatically and add as child when view is clicked?

Comment: @Yaroslav, I am using this RelativeLayout in my BaseAdapter's getView method.

Comment: Maybe, this is because of this line in my BaseAdapter class: this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: @JoeRichard for quick win, just put value inside the height in RelativeLayout root view. like: `android:layout_height="200dp"` or what ever looks good for you. Or, change to root to `FrameLayout` and set wrap_content. Later, I will give example of how to make it work with RelativeLayout and wrap_content and `onMeasure()`. But in general the issue is that RelativeLayout inside ListView, ViewPager, ... can't set match parent to it's rows. And thus the match_parent of views that are inside the RelativeLayout doesn't work.

Comment: @sromku, magic of 200dp worked) however, this is not dynamic!

Comment: @JoeRichard of course it isn't :) you can change to FrameLayout and fix the badge icon position by wraping it with RelativeLayout and then you are back to be dynamic. Or in case of RelativeLayout only as root, you will have to create custom view for your layout and override `onMeasure()` and then set the measured height to your internal views.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this to the LinearLayout:

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Any way use can use this without even using the LinearLayout (with fixing the size of the drawable "big_tick" ):

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:src="@drawable/big_tick" />
```

Comment: alignParentBottom and alignParentTop making child LinearLayout on the Bottom.

Comment: What about fill_parent for height instead of match_parent

Comment: try the RelativeLayout, if didn't work, add view with tranparency 66000000 that matches parent for height and width and make your image view centerInParent

Comment: Man, just remove the linearLayout, use the imageview tick as centerInParent and add a View that alignparentBottom and alignparentTop with the desired transparency, it's not the first time,, android has alot of bugs with gridview..

Comment: would you try this in the getView:  (TextView) ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewContainerId).getLayoutParams()).height= RelativeLayout.MATCH_PARENT;

Comment: It is working) I have added View with #66000000 background and ImageView with layout_centerInParent="true".

Comment: @challanger, could you please post as answer. I think this can be problem to other people also.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using this layout by itself is fine. It is the fact that you are putting it into a `ListView` is causing some sort a havoc.

However, you can force the overlay to align itself `bottom` and `top` with the book layout:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/llBook"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/llBook"
```

After that maybe you still have a few margins to fix, but the two lines above will make the overlay be as big as the book layout.

Answer (score 0):

it is taking the full height of its parent. Get rid of the padding on your child linear layout. Then if that doesn't work. Switch your linearLayout to a relativeLayout. (It's better anyway) another limitation is the actual images you are using. Do they have differing heights?

Comment: thank you for quick response! But my question is about another LinearLayout.... Changing child LinearLayout to RelativeLayout is good idea! I will try it...

Comment: I have tried to change child LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. Unfortunately, no effect!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the LinearLayout totally, use the imageview with src 'tick' as a direct child of the Relative layout with:

```
andriod:centerInParent=true
```

and then add View with the desired background transparency that has

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```